# Delete button on user panel

Tags: php

i was always curious about how many websites have a `delete` button on their user panels.
For example, if a user can submit a post and this must be available on his user control panel to delete it if he wants how would you code this button without any frameworks in php?
What i've dont now its creatre a form with a hiden value, you can see a piece of the code below:

```
<?php foreach ($results as $result): ?>
  <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $result['id'] ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $result['message'] ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $result['name'] ?> </td>
  <td>  
  <form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="checkbox" 
           name="delete_action" 
           value="<?= $result['id'] ?>" 
           style="display:none; visibility:hidden;" 
           checked>
     <input  class="" type="submit" value="Delete">
   </form>
 </td>
 </tr>
```

Time for the php action:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete_action'])) {

$get_id_to_delete = $_POST['delete_action'];

$delete_action = $pdo_testimonials->prepare("DELETE FROM testimonials WHERE id = :id");
$delete_action->bindParam(':id', $get_id_to_delete);

$delete_action->execute();

}
```

So, as you can see the methond is so insecure and easy to mess up. However i've used it only for a control panel which only i have access. I know that i should never use a similar way of adding a delete button on a production website.
Is there any better, more secure and reliable way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple link (GET) showing only when it's content that current user can remove is ok, as long as you check that in PHP again. So:

1. Check if current user can remove element.
2. If so, display (image) link to for example /delete.php?id=2.
3. On page delete.php check if current user can remove element with id = 2.
4. If so, remove element and get back to page. Otherwise display warning.

It can be done with AJAX too, with same steps.